# Incorrect encoding from PHP?

Tags: php, html, encoding, utf-8, pdo

1) I have a table `tbl_Data` in database which has `name` column with text comparision method (?) property set to`utf8_polish_ci`. Works as a charm, when I'm browsing `tbl_Data` through phpMyAdmin.

2) In my html code I've got:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

so seems like I'm sending proper encoding headers for browser...

3) My PDO dsn contains `;charset=UTF-8`, followed from php manual.

4) In my php code I use:

```
foreach(parent::query('SELECT ID,PLName,LatinName from tbl_Data') as $row) {
    $result = $result."
        <tr>
            <td>".utf8_encode($row['PLName'])."</td>
        </tr>
    ";
}
```

Having all of this I'm still getting 'garbage' (=`?`) chars instead of proper polish letters, though some of them are displaying well (phpMyAdmin shows all properly). What I am missing here? Please advice, fellows!

My MySQL Engine is `InnoDB`, webserver: `nginx` with fpm if it is revelant...

Comment: Did you see the comment on the php manual for [utf8_encode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)? namely: "If your text is already in UTF-8, you do not need this function"? What happens if you don't use the `utf8_encode` function?

Comment: If I don't use this function at all, then I'm receiving � from "ó" which was correct earlier using `utf8_encode()`. Rest of missing letters are still "?"

Comment: maby this will help http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: PHP 5.4.10 at this moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so seems like I'm sending proper encoding headers for browser.

Wrong. `<meta>` is not an HTTP header but HTML tag, a non-standard one. So, your code still lacks proper header.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

> My PDO dsn contains ;charset=UTF-8, followed from php manual.

if your PHP version is less than 5.3.6 it won't work either. use `SET NAMES utf8` regular query instead

Comment: I've added `header(...)` line just after my `ob_start();` line and the chars are still incorrect. The only difference is if I use `utf8_encode()` or not. If code uses it, only one letter is displayed correctly `ó`, if not none of them are. `php --version` gives me: `PHP 5.4.10 (cli) (built: Dec 22 2012 22:12:36)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies`

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use `utf8_encode()` if your text is already UTF-8 encoded.

A potential issue might be your version of PHP. The `;charset=UTF-8` element of your DSN is only supported by PHP version >= 5.3.6. **Prior to 5.3.6 this element was silently ignored** (instead of issuing a warning). More information and a workaround for this are available in the docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

Comment: `php --version` in cli gives me: `PHP 5.4.10 (cli) (built: Dec 22 2012 22:12:36)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
` so it seems like it should work...

Answer (score 1):

Charset UTF-8 is good (in your html) :P

Try this.. (use new, experimental table for this, to check it out because I have no idea if your PHP script is cleaning $_POST entries for example, or doing something at all..)

1. create column set to `utf8_bin` (not utf_ci_polish) named "polish_title"
2. Before PHP passes (text input, polish) data to mysql `INSERT (or update)` covert those with this (PHP integrated) function

   $polish_input = **htmlspecialchars**($input_polish_data);

   INSERT INTO table_name (polish_title) values ('$polish_input');

You will see strange data in mysql table (via phpmyadmin) when polish signs are part of your input what is normal (or blobed), but good ones (polish native) on your site when you get mysql data out ;)

If this gonna work, ALL your mqsql (text) columns should be changed to utf8_bin. And to easy entries on yourself, you can create function which can "clean" all $_POST inputs on your website before those inputs engage to mysql DB.

Big plus on this is that visitors from other countries will see your native letters & signs (what is also important).

**Edit** (thx to Common Sense user input)

ANd yeah include this as a MUST also in your header

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not comment on your post.....so I suggest here~_~
From [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php), it said utf8_encode — Encodes an [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) string to UTF-8
therefore, my question is: is your output is ISO-8859-1?
may be you could create a normal English test record and try again.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I've added a test column with default settings and populated it with all possible polish letters. phpMyAdmin shows great, but website shows: `?????�??`

Comment: how about normal English, just like abcdefg?

Comment: I just search on stackoverflow, and guess you may refer to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241709/utf8-encode-does-not-produce-right-result

Answer (score -1):

In your HTML code, try:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```