# Replace accented letters in mysql column not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Why won't the following query work on the accented characters in my column?

```
UPDATE people SET firstname = REPLACE(firstname,'à','a');
```

It works fine when I do:

```
UPDATE people SET firstname = REPLACE(firstname,'e','a');
```

The database character set is utf8mb4.  I've tried changing the column's collation, but that didn't work.

**Edit:** I added this before my query and it worked:

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8mb4");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accented characters in mySQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083847/accented-characters-in-mysql-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this -> [Accented characters in mySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083847/accented-characters-in-mysql-table)

I think that's what you are needing to do for your DB to accept accented characters.

Comment: Thanks.  I updated my question with the line that worked for me.